# iOS + MacOS app paid app, best user experience to purchase once and enjoy on all devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, app-store, mac-app-store

I am building a universal app (iPhone+iPad), that will also work on OSX. With Universal apps, the user purchase once, and then can use it on all their iOS devices
I do not think it is possible to extend that to OSX/Mac App Store.

- I want to avoid the user having to purchase twice, once for iOS, once for OSX.
- I want the user to be able to purchase from any device, not have to go through one platform then the next, in a specific order
- The app would have to be on App Store and Mac App Store, so whichever mechanism is being used, it would have to be compliant with the review guidelines

What do you think is the best user experience for this kind of scenario?

Comment: Apple doesn't support this.  And any scheme outside the 2 App stores is likely to present problems with the user experience. Perhaps just letting the customer pay for each separately would provide the best experience, if not the best price.

Comment: @hotpaw2 In some cases, having the user buy different versions make sense. By design though, this app requires the user to have both the OSX and iOS version, so it's terrible experience to have to buy both, since buying one of them isn't enough to do anything. With a previous version of this app, I had the free version on the Mac App Store, and paid version on iOS, but lots of users think of the free version as a bait and feel tricked, which is why I am looking for a better user experience

Comment: It's usually recommended to ignore users who can't read and complain about free apps.  There are too many of them.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, you are right, it isn't possible to create a fully universal app (iOS + mac os).

Even submitting applications to both iOS and Mac OS require to pay two different developer programs.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best approach here is to offer the upgrade only on one of the platforms (probably ios)
You must have some kind of server-client relationship when the two connect right?
And I'm assuming the pairing can achieve things that two iPhones together (or 2 macs) can't?
Why does the the mac end not just connect to a mobile device which either has or has not purchased the upgrade?
Sometimes the simplest way is the best way

Answer (score -1):

Well, a way to "cheat" would be to use inAppPurchase

both versions (os X and iOS) are free, but an unlock code is required to use them
this unlock code can be purchased using inAppPurchase => the user is then given a code he can enter on the other version in order to unlock it.

Comment: Jerome, this doesn't work for many reasons. First, the app has only one main functionality, so if the in app purchase is tied to that functionality, this means the app would be useless when first downloaded. Bad user experience + probably rejected by Apple. Second thing, this means functionality could be unlocked by entering a code that could have been acquired by a mechanism other than in app purchase. Apple rejects unlocking functionality by entering a code.

Comment: Jerome, just for future references, I believe you probably wanted to post this kind of entries as comments rather than answers. Answers are for things you know work for sure, brainstorming posting are better as comments than answers